# Eclipse CDT disabled code background color

Tags: eclipse, preprocessor, color-scheme

Facing a weird code coloring issue when trying to view disabled code.

For blocks of code that are disabled with `#ifdef` or `#ifndef` statements, I get a grey/white background:

[image: Eclipse grey background for disabled code]

However, when the code is enabled, things are okay:

[image: Eclipse correct background for enabled code]

Where can I find this color property in the properties menu? I can't find anything about disabled code, and it isn't under any of the pre-processor color coding menus.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://github.com/eclipse-color-theme/eclipse-color-theme/issues/35):

> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Editor, “Highlight inactive code” checked, Appearance color options: Inactive code highlight.